# Java application with fancy Drag & Drop

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, awt

Is there any framework or tool to develop a fancy Java application - an user interface with a nice drag & drop?

For example like this one from Mac OS:
http://appzapper.com/

[image]

It does not need to have a Mac OS look and feel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enjoy the screenshot by just enjoying it :)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class DragHereIcon implements Icon {
  private int size = 80;
  private float a = 4f;
  private float b = 8f;
  private int r = 16;
  private int f = size/4;
  private Font font = new Font("Monospace", Font.PLAIN, size);
  private FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);
  private Shape s = new TextLayout("\u21E9", font, frc).getOutline(null);
  private Color linec = Color.GRAY;
  @Override public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.translate(x, y);

    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(a));
    g2.setPaint(linec);
    g2.draw(new RoundRectangle2D.Float(a,a,size-2*a-1,size-2*a-1,r,r));

    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(b));
    g2.setColor(UIManager.getColor("Panel.background"));
    g2.drawLine(1*f,0*f,1*f,4*f);
    g2.drawLine(2*f,0*f,2*f,4*f);
    g2.drawLine(3*f,0*f,3*f,4*f);
    g2.drawLine(0*f,1*f,4*f,1*f);
    g2.drawLine(0*f,2*f,4*f,2*f);
    g2.drawLine(0*f,3*f,4*f,3*f);

    g2.setPaint(linec);
    Rectangle2D b = s.getBounds();
    Point2D.Double p = new Point2D.Double(
        b.getX() + b.getWidth()/2d, b.getY() + b.getHeight()/2d);
    AffineTransform toCenterAT = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(
        size/2d - p.getX(), size/2d - p.getY());
    g2.fill(toCenterAT.createTransformedShape(s));
    g2.translate(-x,-y);
    g2.dispose();
  }
  @Override public int getIconWidth()  {
    return size;
  }
  @Override public int getIconHeight() {
    return size;
  }
  public static JComponent makeUI() {
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new DragHereIcon());
    label.setText("<html>Drag <b>Stuff</b> Here");
    label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
    label.setFont(new Font("Monospace", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(label);
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8,8,8,8));
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(DragHereIcon.makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 200);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

See the [Introduction to DnD](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html) in the tutorial to develop some code that works.

---

> *Please see the screenshot on the first post to see what is a specification of nice.*
>
> The only custom part is the dashed border of the downward pointing arrow, and the text below it. You might use an icon (for the arrow/border) in a `JLabel` with HTML formatting for the text, to achieve that.

### E.G.

[image: Icon with HTML formatted text in label]

```
package test.t100.t006;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class DrawLabel {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                // substitute for downward pointing arrow with dashed border
                Object obj = UIManager.getDefaults()
                        .get("OptionPane.warningIcon");
                if (obj!=null && obj instanceof Icon) {
                    Icon icon = (Icon)obj;
                    String text = "<html><body>Drag <em><b>Stuff</b></em> Here";
                    JLabel l = new JLabel(
                            text, icon, SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
                    l.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
                    l.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                            null, l);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see the screenshot on the first post to see what is a specification of nice.

Comment: You know exactly, what he means. ;) He wants a space (JLabel or so) where he can drop files in, like in this AppZapper. Your link will help him and then he can come back with more specific questions if there are any. +1